# Input of CRC when the input is random in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, crc

I have this code for CRC code in MATLAB, `msg` is the data and `poly` is the generator function.

```
msg=[1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 ]; 
poly=[1 0 1 1]; 
[M, N]=size(poly);
mseg=[msg zeros(1,N-1)];
[q, r]=deconv(mseg,poly);
r=abs(r); 
for i=1:length(r)
        a=r(i);
        if ( mod(a,2)== 0 )
            r(i)=0;
        else
            r(i)=1;
        end end

    crc=r(length(msg)+1:end) frame = bitor(mseg,r)
```

It works well but I want to do it for random `msg` with size of 7.
 I used this but it has error.

```
msg = randi([0, 1], 7,1);
```

The error is:

> Error using horzcat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not
>   consistent.

please help me with this problem.

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: You have a lot of previous questions that have very good answers. Consider revisiting them and marking the best answer that solves your problem as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/) by clicking **`✔`**, on the left side of the answers (one answer per post can be marked as accepted). You can also [upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/) all the helpful answers by clicking **`▲`**, on the left side of the answers. This is the least that you can do for the people who are volunteering their time for your problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:  `msg = randi([0, 1], 1, 7);` ?

Notice the switching of the `7, 1` to `1, 7`.  Please see if this solves your problem.